# Infura and Brownie: HTTPError: 502 Server Error: Bad Gateway for url

Tags: http, solidity, brownie

I am getting this error every time I try to deploy my smart contract.

```
HTTPError: 502 Server Error: Bad Gateway for url
```

It seems Infura requires authentication for API calls as of today. How can I do this using brownie?

Answer (score 0):

To add api_key to your brownie you need to add followings to your `.env` file created in the root of your project:

```
export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=<your_api_key>
```

then go to your infura account and create a project then open `Manage Key` after that copy your key and add it to the line above. To make it available for brwonie to use run line below in terminal :

`source .env`

Check your code again and let me know if it worked